# Jetty 11 - Uploading fails only when file is a video

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded jetty server that handles file uploads. 
When uploading **any file** of **any size** the file gets uploaded correctly and the request ends. For some reason though, when the uploaded file is a video file, jetty starts the `request.getParts()` as usual but then it never ends, and remains idle indefinetly end eventually ends in a timeout. 
I have tried many other file formats, images, zips, pdfs and they all work great.
The problem appears uploading specific formats, i dont know if it is actually because they are videos or something else, but i downloaded many video samples from the internet and tried uploading them to jetty and the problem appears for example with .mp4, .3gp and.mov, but it does not for an .mkv file.

Here is the last lines of jetty log before it stops:

```
21:38:08:628 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: produceRawContent updated rawContentArrived to 12834785 and firstByteTimeStamp to 109772550050391 AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=null,t=null,i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8640}]
21:38:08:628 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: produceRawContent produced Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null} AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=null,t=null,i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8640}]
21:38:08:628 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: null interceptor, transformed content = raw content AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=null,i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8640}]
21:38:08:629 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: transformed content is not empty AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8641}]
21:38:08:629 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: returning transformed content AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8641}]
21:38:08:629 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: available = 8192 AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8641}]
21:38:08:629 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: available=8192 HttpInput@1246248597 cs=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} cp=org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingContentProducer@6a92fa25 eof=false
21:38:08:630 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: checkMinDataRate [m=0,t=109772550050391] AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8642}]
21:38:08:630 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: nextTransformedContent AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8642}]
21:38:08:630 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: returning transformed content AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8642}]
21:38:08:631 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: nextContent = Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null} AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8643}]
21:38:08:631 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: onReadIdle HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0}
21:38:08:631 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: nextContent async producer returned Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=0,l=8192,c=8192,r=8192]={<<<\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&M+\x95%\x7f\xDf\x03\x8aI\xE4'$\x0e!\xA6\x13...\xBd\xFd\xD9\x9a\xEa<\x93\xC2\xE5ux"vIf"LF\xA2t\x03=:>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null}
21:38:08:631 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: read produced 8192 byte(s) HttpInput@1246248597 cs=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} cp=org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingContentProducer@6a92fa25 eof=false
21:38:08:632 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: reclaim Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=8192,l=8192,c=8192,r=0]={\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&...LF\xA2t\x03=:<<<>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null} AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=8192,l=8192,c=8192,r=0]={\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&...LF\xA2t\x03=:<<<>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},t=Content@714714d8{DirectByteBufferR@48200ff0[p=8192,l=8192,c=8192,r=0]={\x1de.C\x1f\\\x1f]&...LF\xA2t\x03=:<<<>>>},spc=false,eof=false,err=null},i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8644}]
21:38:08:632 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@373d0634::SocketChannelEndPoint@ffd712a{l=/127.0.0.1:42069,r=/127.0.0.1:41214,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=5/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@373d0634[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,12834785 of 13785725},g=HttpGenerator@16634b69{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8644}
21:38:08:632 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: parseOctetContent(HeapByteBuffer@72ad9ab9[p=0,l=16384,c=16384,r=16384]={<<<N\x15#\xA2\xCa0\x01)\xD9a\x9f\xE8-\x99\x9c\xC5\xF4u\xEf\xE7\xC0\xBfS\xA9\x98...\xBd\xC7\xCc\x9a\x85\x02\x1c\xE5\x13\xBf\xC8qj\xFb}\x06O[\xF1\xE8\xE4)\xDd>>>})
21:38:08:632 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: Content=HeapByteBuffer@4aec8a46[p=0,l=16384,c=16384,r=16384]={<<<N\x15#\xA2\xCa0\x01)\xD9a\x9f\xE8-\x99\x9c\xC5\xF4u\xEf\xE7\xC0\xBfS\xA9\x98...\xBd\xC7\xCc\x9a\x85\x02\x1c\xE5\x13\xBf\xC8qj\xFb}\x06O[\xF1\xE8\xE4)\xDd>>>}, Last=false MultiPartParser{s=OCTETS}
21:38:08:633 [qtp915349526-16] DEBUG: nextTransformedContent AsyncContentProducer@67554002[r=null,t=null,i=null,error=false,c=HttpChannelOverHttp@6f3547cb{s=HttpChannelState@18720e7a{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=http://192.168.1.100/api/v1/files/upload,age=8645}]
```

And this is how i set the multipart config ( it's in the server initialization ):

```
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setOutputBufferSize(1024);

ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
connector.setPort(port);

server.addConnector(connector);

ServletHolder jerseyServlet = contextHandler.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/api/v1/*");
jerseyServlet.getRegistration().setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/storage/tmp", -1L, -1L, 1));
```

Let me remind you that as everything is right now the file upload works perfectly for any file except those video files.
Thanks for the help

EDIT:

To upload the video i am using PostMan with the following headers:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data
X-Auth-Token:{{token}}
X-UserId:{{userid}}
... plus the default postman headers
```

I also have an angular application that performs these requests with the following headers ( copy pasted from chrome console ):

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,it-IT;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13785725
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarymajD2TkV6jdqloTj
Host: 192.168.1.100
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
X-Auth-Token: mytoken
X-UserId: myuserid
```

I get the same result in both cases.
Just for context, even though i don't think it matters, i have a virtual machine ( Ubuntu 20.04 ) hosting the jetty server app that receives the requests, and the angular application is running locally on my windows 10 PC, in the developement server that vscode provides

Comment: What are you using to upload the video? and what do the request headers look like? (we need more details).   The last log shows that the output is OPEN and the input is IDLE (meaning it's not finished, and waiting on more content).

Comment: Hi, i just edited the question with more details on the problem, as you suggested

Comment: What version of postman are you using? as the one you are using seems to have the old bug with the `Connection: keep-alive` header still (that header should not be sent when using HTTP/1.1, only when using HTTP/1.0).

Comment: I could try to update it and see. But still, does not explain how i can reproduce the bug in my angular app. Will try to update postman though

Answer (score 1):

13MB is a minuscule size to upload, the Jetty project uploads 1GB, 4GB, and 10GB files during it's unit testing both as a straight `POST` and again as a `multipart/form-data`.

See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.6/jetty-webapp/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/HugeResourceTest.java

I also ran a quick test using a more reliable http client than PostMan.

The server, running Jetty 11.0.6, with the demo modules enable.

```sh
$ java -jar ~/code/jetty/distros/jetty-home-11.0.6/start.jar 
2021-09-17 14:24:28.360:WARN :oe.jetty:main: demo-realm is deployed. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
2021-09-17 14:24:28.401:INFO :oejs.Server:main: jetty-11.0.6; built: 2021-06-29T16:16:33.537Z; git: 69469432898becda3aed32a32d4b0adbb7b6daee; jvm 11.0.12+7
2021-09-17 14:24:28.437:INFO :oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/webapps/]
2021-09-17 14:24:28.813:WARN :oejshC.ROOT:main: The test-jetty webapp is deployed. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
2021-09-17 14:24:28.957:INFO :oejss.DefaultSessionIdManager:main: Session workerName=node0
2021-09-17 14:24:29.022:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2609b277{Test WebApp,/,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ROOT_war-_-any-/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/webapps/ROOT.war}
2021-09-17 14:24:29.182:WARN :oejshC.test:main: The test-jetty webapp is deployed. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
2021-09-17 14:24:29.246:INFO :oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@e6516e{Test WebApp,/test,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-demo-jetty_war-_test-any-/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/webapps/demo-jetty.war}
2021-09-17 14:24:29.255:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4e9658b5{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-09-17 14:24:29.267:INFO :oejs.Server:main: Started Server@51891008{STARTING}[11.0.6,sto=5000] @1561ms
```

Next, the file I'm going to test the upload with ...

```sh
$ ls -la security-cam.mp4 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joakim joakim 2394313303 Sep 17 14:23 security-cam.mp4
$ file security-cam.mp4 
security-cam.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

That's 2.4GB

Lets upload using curl, with multipart, and without the `Expect: 100-Continue` (like your headers show)

```sh
$ curl --verbose \
  --output multipart-response.html \
  --form file=@security-cam.mp4 \
  --header "Expect: " \
  http://localhost:8080/dump/info
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /dump/info HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 2394313511
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b3d2869d036926f9
> 
} [65536 bytes data]
 88 2283M    0     0   88 2016M      0  1006M  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1005M* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node03eutgygnhty4ltv47atz8yfb12.node0; Path=/
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 10721
< Server: Jetty(11.0.6)
< 
{ [10721 bytes data]
100 2283M  100 10721  100 2283M   4704  1001M  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1001M
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

So it sent 2.4GB and received and html response with some details about the request, parsed the entire request body content with `HttpServletRequest.getParts()` and the results from the individual `javax.servlet.http.Part` is as shown as ...

```sh
$ html2text multipart-response.html | grep -A5 "Parts"
Parts:
        Part{n=file,fn=security-cam.mp4,ct=application/octet-
    file: stream,s=2394313303,tmp=true,file=/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/
        base11-demos/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ROOT_war-_-any-/upload/
        MultiPart7325738426025573814}
```

Yup, all 2.4GB were seen by the Servlet as an upload.

Are they the same?  did it all upload without issue?

```sh
[client]$ sha1sum security-cam.mp4 
85454d56bc8315fa0484d4d5a9cb9ad54933fbab  security-cam.mp4
[client]$ sha1sum /home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ROOT_war-_-any-/upload/MultiPart7325738426025573814
85454d56bc8315fa0484d4d5a9cb9ad54933fbab  /home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/bases/base11-demos/work/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ROOT_war-_-any-/upload/MultiPart7325738426025573814
```

Yup, the same file, size, and contents.

At this point the issue doesn't seem to be in Jetty.
Perhaps Jersey? or more likely PostMan?

If you can replicate this issue in a small testcase, you can try contacting the Jetty developers with that reproduction case at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues  we might be able to narrow down where the problem in your 3rd party libraries exists.

Comment: Thanks for the many details. Turns out i had two problems...the first problem was related to headers and how i performed the request, which was not a big deal but i solved it thanks to your hints, that it probably jetty was not the problem. The second problem has nothing to do with jetty or http at all, but i have a third party library for generating the file thumbnails, which for some reason gets stuck when creating thumbnail for mp4 files right at the end of my request (so getting my request stuck).